# Viewing Partially Downloaded PDF File?

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader, pdf-reader

Today I was downloading a PDF File (size: 200+ MB) from a HTTP link, which ended when I only had 150MB.  When I tried to open this partially downloaded PDF file in Acrobat Reader, it gave an error.

Is there a way to view a partially downloaded PDF File?

Comment: for what OS?

Comment: I am looking this for Windows OS.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's almost impossible because PDF consists of the different data chunks (like textes, fonts, colors) and so called dictionary saved at the end of the file. This part (dictionary) has all the information about where this chunks are placed inside the file. So without this information any software just can guess and might be completely blind trying to connect all these things together

Answer (score 0):

Try [Sumathra](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/index.html). Its a free opensouce tool and I am successful in some cases. But not sure :)